# LOCATION_CHANGE not fired for 302 redirect from Adobe AIR 3.0 HTML component

Tags: air, adobe

In Adobe Air 2.7, you could listen for a LOCATION_CHANGE event to detect 302 redirects.

In Adobe Air 3.0, it seems that this event is no longer fired. I can't find documentation suggesting why - I am in the process of reporting it as a bug, but wanted to see if anyone had knew why this event is missing.

Thanks :)

Comment: I agree, this is a bug. I prefer that it fires an additional LocationChangeEvent.REDIRECT event, which would also be cancelable

Answer (score 1):

Just listen to Event.COMPLETE instead